# Android: Loading off-screen GridView items

Tags: android, gridview

Normally a gridview only has the items that are visible on the screen loaded in memory. Is it possible to give an "offscreen limit" for it to load an X amount of items / rows above and below the currently visible elements?

Comment: I'm doing some research on this, found [this](http://lucasr.org/2013/01/06/introducing-smoothie/), still not sure if it actually pre-loads images offscreen or not, sure seems so. Will be back if I find something that works.